# How to show more than 5 posts of the category?

Tags: categories

I use a LearnMore Template, but it isn't possible to add more than five articles to each category, and this is in many templates(Mywiki, IKnow, LikeAWiki &MyKnowledgeBase).

**What is the code to fix this and where would I add the code on which file?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are talking about **Learn More theme** by Humble themes. Just downloaded this theme and checked source code.
File `get_posts.php` has an argument, which returns only 5 posts.
This file is located in theme folder: `learnmore/inc/functions/get_posts.php`

```
    $args = array(
        'orderby'    => get_theme_mod( 'kb_article_orderby', 'date' ),
        'order'      => get_theme_mod( 'kb_article_order', 'ASC' ),
        //here it goes
        'numberposts' => get_theme_mod( 'kb_article_count', 5 ),
        'category'    => $category->term_id,
    );
```

But I think you don't need to change it in a source code. This theme has an options or theme page, where I see this text:

> All Setting, Theme Options, Widgets and Menus are available via
> Customize screen. Have a quick look or start customization!

So I recommend you to check customizer settings, you should find there an option to change the number of posts per category.

### Update

> how can I remove the "View all articles" sentence -under the posts-?

You can find this link in a `layout-1.php` file, which located: learnmore/template-parts/layout-1.php, lines 56-58. Remove this code or modify it, it's up to you.

```
<a class="learnmore-category-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_category_link( $category ) ); ?>">
    <?php esc_html_e( 'View all articles →', 'learnmore' ); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: thanks, brilliant solution. Do you know how can I remove the "View all articles" sentence -under the posts-?

Comment: Check my answer, I updated it)